# Split CSV file in Python with semicolon separating the records

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi

I have a CSV file with 288 records in the following format (extract of first 3 records only)

```
20210402,23:55,37684,4.758,0,0,0.000,16238,510,NaN,242.0,-500.000,0.000,500.000,-500.000,10.000,NaN;20210402,23:50,37684,4.758,0,0,0.000,16195,540,NaN,243.0,-530.000,0.000,530.000,-530.000,10.000,NaN;20210402,23:45,37684,4.758,0,0,0.000,16150,540,NaN,243.0,-550.000,0.000,550.000,-550.000,0.000,NaN;
```

This file is saved as continuous string if I open it in Notepad. If I open it in excel then each of the values are in a column. The last column of the first record is shared with the first column of the seconded record and so on, as per below

[image: excel]

I am trying to spit the string so there are 288 records using

```
with open('dailyData.csv','r') as file:
    array = file.readlines()
    array = [row.split(';') for row in array]
```

The ";" is converted to ", " but it does not split the string

[['20210402,23:55,37684,4.758,0,0,0.000,16238,510,NaN,242.0,-500.000,0.000,500.000,-500.000,10.000,NaN', '20210402,23:50,37684...

any ideas?

UPDATE

I have tried to use Pandas

```
array = pandas.read_csv('dailyData.csv', delimiter=';', header=None)
print(array.columns)
```

This returns

Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
...
277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286],
dtype='int64', length=287)

which means I can address any record but not elements within the record.

Just looking to be able to address as array[r][c] where r is 0 to 287 and c is 0 to 16.

thanks

Hi Kamil, I have tried

```
 with open('dailyData.csv') as file:
    for x in file:
        columns = x.split(';')
        for y in columns:
            lines = y.split(',')
            print(lines)
```

This prints the lines but dos not create the array that I can address.

Comment: It looks like the records are separated by a semicolon and the elements in a record by a comma.

Comment: based on the your details, i can get a list of list. inner list has 4 rows.

Comment: Your output shows exactly what you want.  the string has been separated by `;`. You can access it by `array[0][0], array[0][1], ......`. might be you were confused by `list` notation in python.

Comment: Hi Simon, I can't access the values with array[0][n] with n >0 as the data is all in the same row. I need to split the data into rows at the ';' then split the data sting at the ',' so I could address the array elements. once I have it in an addressable matrix then add the values in the columns to create totals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
with open("data.csv") as f:
    array = [l.split(",") for l in f.readline().split(";") if l]

print(len(array))
print(array[1][0])
```

Output: where `3` is the number of lists within the array and each list has `16` values.

```
3
20210402
```

The above allows for:

> Just looking to be able to address as array[r][c] where r is 0 to 287
> and c is 0 to 16.

I've assumed that your data is one long continuous string, as shown in your question.

If you feel like it, this can be easily dumped to a `pandas DataFrame` and then to a proper `.csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("data.csv") as f:
    array = [l.split(",") for l in f.readline().split(";") if l]

pd.DataFrame(array).to_csv("your_array.csv", header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
with open('dailyData.csv','r') as file:
    array = file.readlines()
    array = [x.split(',') for x in row.split(';') for row in array]
```

Comment: Thanks but it produces a name 'row' is not defined error